# C# Fat Lost caculating

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, counter

Hi I am trying to make my code count up 10,15,20,25....60  and then times each count by 3.9cal  and display both but for some reason my code wont count down could you help me?

Please keep the code simple since I am still learning :)

```
double lost;
int counter = 5;
while (counter <= 60)   
{
  if (counter * 5 == 0)
  {
    lost = counter * 3.9;
    Console.WriteLine("Minutes spend: {0}    Fat Lost: {1}", counter, lost);
    counter++;
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Your WriteLine will never execute because `counter * 5` will never equal zero.

Comment: seems infinite loop issues?

Comment: Seems so any help? O_O how do I stop my loop before it sucks in the universe?

Comment: I would suggest you use a for loop, might make your life easier.

Comment: It seems like you might want `if (counter % 5 == 0)` so that it will be true for every multiple of 5.  If that is the case, then you can also just increment `counter` by 5 each iteration, by changing `counter++` to `counter += 5`

Comment: 5, 10, 15 ....60 is not count down. It is count skip by 5. Count down will be 10,9, 8, 7 ...

Comment: I got it fix there was 2 problems. The counter++ had to be outside the if statement and the readline had to be outside the while statment. They were stopping the each other lol thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your IF statement will never be true since you start you start your loop with counter = 5

You need to move you counter++ outside of the if statement to fix the problem

```
double lost;
int counter = 5;
while (counter <= 60)
{
    if (counter % 5 == 0)
    {
        lost = counter * 3.9;
        Console.WriteLine("Minutes spend: {0}    Fat Lost: {1}", counter,     lost);
    }
    counter++;
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: why is readline inside the while loop in every answer. Because SO did so.?

Comment: @malkassem It still seems to not wanting to count down 5,10,15...60 it just stays at 5 :/

Comment: why do you have the if statement to begin with.  I would remove it completely.

Comment: count++; needs to be count +=5 to give the user what he is looking for (5,10,15...)

Comment: @MillerKoijam Thanks yeah I had to move the readline outside the  answer thanks you helped me alot thanks both of you lol

Answer (score 1):

Try this (if I understand correctly):

```
double lost;
int counter = 5;
while (counter <= 60)   
{
  if (counter % 5 == 0)
  {
    lost = counter * 3.9;
    Console.WriteLine("Minutes spend: {0}    Fat Lost: {1}", counter, lost);            
  }
  counter++;
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: +1 . Also he can remove `if statement` and  put `counter += 5;`

Comment: @SaifHamed, but then the `Console.ReadLine()` wouldn't be called 5 times between the WriteLine....

Comment: You are right, but i see it was useless. also some one edit his answer to be just like your answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can be a simple for loop, as in:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 60; i+=5) 
        Console.WriteLine("Minutes spend: {0} - Fat Lost: {1}", i, i*3.9);
```

However, you can use LINQ/Enumerable methods for this if you'd like. I usually find them clearer for loops of this nature:

```
var a = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new {Minutes = i * 5, Lost = i * 5 * 3.9});
foreach(var entry in a)
    Console.WriteLine ("Minutes spent: {0} - Fat Lost: {1}", entry.Minutes, entry.Lost);
```

Comment: Unless you didn't read this.... "Please keep the code simple since I am still learning :)"

Comment: @DavidN Is there a simpler way I havent learn var or foreach yet your code seems to futuristic for a newbie like me :(

Comment: @TheBoringGuy Hopefully this will give you the impetus to :)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers explein well how to fix your code but here's a way of doing it with a simple loop.

```
for (int minute = 10; minute <= 60; minute += 5)
    Console.WriteLine("Minutes spend: {0}    Fat Lost: {1}", minute, minute * 3.9);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to count by 5, and multiply the counter by 3.9, you could do this:

```
double lost;
int counter = 5;
while (counter <= 60)   
{
  lost = counter * 3.9;
  Console.WriteLine("Minutes spend: {0}    Fat Lost: {1}", counter, lost);            
  counter += 5;
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```